# if(true) return игнорируется

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который возвращает сложную переменную. Ее вычисление занимает не так мало времени, поэтому сделал что-то похожее на кэш.

```
public static Forge DeserializeForge(bool cleanCache = false) {
    if (CachedForge != null && !cleanCache)
        return CachedForge;
    _semaphoreSlim.Wait();
    ...Процесс получения переменной
    _semaphoreSlim.Release();

    return CachedForge;
}
```

Дебажил программу, и обнаружил, что у меня очень часто вызывается метод, задействованный в получении переменной. Дебаггер показал мне вот такую интересную проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дебаггер показывает, что условие в `if` верно, те у нас должен был исполниться return, и выйти из функции, однако он идет дальше. Почему?

Comment: А чему `CachedForge` равен?  `&&` подразумевает, что оба условия должны вернуть `true`

Comment: Это уже вторая итерация метода, следовательно CachedForge уже не null, что подтверждает нам дебаггер.

Comment: есть вероятность что продолжение подхвачено из другого потока

Comment: Зачем городить огороды с семафорами? Тут вполне себе впишется `Lazy<T>`. Ну или, если любите олдскул, то можете попробовать блокировку с двойной проверкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял из-за чего это происходило. Видимо метод вызывался слишком быстро, а вычисление значения происходило дольше, чем происходили новые запросы к методу.

Таким образом у нас вызывается метод в первый раз, условие ложно, идем обновлять переменную, блокируем семафор, вычисляем переменную, (пока она вычисляется она всё-еще null), в это время метод вызывается еще несколько раз, условие ложно, и все эти вызовы останавливаются ждать освобождения семафора. После переменная уже со значением, что и показывает дебаггер, но у нас скопились запросы, исполняющиеся по очереди из-за семафора.